# Bash : Prune aligment from specific sequences give the locus name and taxon name

Tags: bash, awk, alignment

I have a set of phylip format aligment, one per locus.

I wish to prune specific sequences given a list of locus and taxa.

My phylip alignment are named this way : locus0385_gbrelaxed.phy , with loci name from locus0003 to locus1370.
I have created a file containing the sequence I wish to prune. First column is the locus, the second the taxa. (to prune.txt file).

```
locus0003;RROU00279_0101
```

My idea is to enter in the $1 file, and grep the $2 in it. Then I wish to delete the corresponding line.

I tried this :

```
cat to_prune.txt | while read line
do
  awk -F ";"  '{print "ls" $1 "_gbrelaxed.phy" "| cat | grep"}'
done
```

or this

```
cat to_prune.txt | while read line
do
  awk -F ";"  'BEGIN{print "ls "}{print $1}{print "_gbrelaxed.phy"} END{print"| cat | grep" $2}'
done
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, but calling `awk` once for each line is almost certainly the wrong way to go. `awk` can iterate over `to_prune` itself.

Comment: At the same time, it's not clear you need `awk` at *all*, if you just want to run a particular pipeline for each pair. `while IFS=';' read locus taxa; do ls "${locus}_gbrelaxed" | grep; done < to_prune.txt` maybe? (The `cat` is useless.)

Comment: In generic terms: Are you trying to extract certain keywords from certain files, where the association of filename and keyword is maintained in a file you generated?

Comment: @karakfa, that's it. @ chepner, it helps a lot. I thus try the command while IFS=';' read locus taxa; do grep $taxa $locus"_gbrelaxed.phy" > $locus.match; done < to_prune.txt
But this does not return the line match the taxa. The idea in then to remove them from the file.